# Unable to create html email asset in SFMC using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, content-builder, sfmcadmin

I am trying to create an html email, which is already stored in a field of one of my Data extension. The email is retrieved correctly and even i am able to print it in cloud page, but i am getting bad request error on creating the asset in sfmc. I am able to create the email with single line of code like "h2 Test Email /h2--", but when its the whole html content, code is breaking.
My code is given below,

```
"<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core", "1"); 
    var myDE = DataExtension.Init("external key");
    var filter = {Property:"Contact Key",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"5424"};
    var data = myDE.Rows.Retrieve(filter); 
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
  {
    if(csv in data[i])
    {
      var html = data[i]["csv"];
      
    }
  }
  if(html)
  {
    var restInstanceUrl = "https://subdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/",
        accessToken     = "";
 
 try {

        var payload = {
            name: "My HTML Email",
            channels: {
                email: true,
                web: false
            },
            views: {
                html: {
                    content: html
                },
                text: {},
                subjectline: {
                    content: "Hello, this is my subject line"
                },
                preheader: {
                    content: "and this is my preheader"
                }
            },
            assetType: {
                name: "htmlemail",
                id: 208
            },
          category: {id: "398609" },
          contentType:"text/html"
        };

        var endpoint = restInstanceUrl + "asset/v1/content/assets";

        var request = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(endpoint);
            request.emptyContentHandling = 0;
            request.retries = 2;
            request.continueOnError = true;
            request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            request.method = "POST";
            request.contentType = "application/json";
            request.postData = Stringify(payload);

        var results = request.send();

        var result = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(results.content));

        Write("success");
  
 } catch(error) {
   
        Write("failed");
        
    } 
  }
</script>"
```

Could you suggest any possible solutions?

Thanks

Comment: is all the html escaped within the DE?

Comment: yes, i have updated it in the html file before pushing the content to data extension.